# Supernatural, good demons?

Tags: supernatural

Now I'm fairly new to the *Supernatural* franchise (I just started season 3) but I ended up either accidentally reading too much wikia's or my friends have told me about things so I know a fair bit into the future of the show.

I was wondering, since there are obviously angels who have turned "evil" by way of killing other angels or just in generally doing evil things, can a demon in the show be "good"? Ruby kinda helped Sam (from what I've seen so far) but she just wanted Lucifer out.

Answer (score 3):

#### There are no good demons in the Supernatural franchise. While the behavior of the Angels has left everyone wondering how they could be considered the good guys, there are no demons who embark upon a path of righteousness as a lifestyle choice.

- That said, we are often shown that while demons are prone to lie, cheat, steal and kill, the more powerful demons will often put aside their personal urges for the aforementioned in search of a greater opportunity for mayhem or personal gain. The very heart of the demon philosophy is "selfish is good".
- The demon [Ruby](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Ruby) is often cited as being a "good demon" but her goals were selfish and even though she was sexually active with Sam, she had no intention of helping the Winchesters. She took advantage of his connection with her to exploit him into completing her mission.
- The greatest example of this is [Crowley, self-proclaimed King of Hell](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Crowley). Crowley has repeated worked with the Winchesters in order to further his schemes and almost always promptly screws the Brothers Winchester as soon as he gets what he wants.
- Crowley is a bastard willing to do almost anything to get what he wants; the epitome of demonic behavior. Only read the hidden text below after season 8...

> Crowley allied with Sam and Dean in Season 5 against Lucifer to obtain the Four Horsemen's rings with them, then with Castiel to obtain the power of Purgatory and briefly Raphael in Season 6, and then with the Winchesters again in Season 7 against the Leviathans.

The moral line for Supernatural baddies is pretty clear most of the time. If you are anti-human, (use Humans for your dark magic rituals, prey on or eat Humans) you are a bad guy and if you cross the Winchesters (or any other decent Hunter) you get what's coming to you.

**As an aside:** the closest we come to seeing a baddie turn "relatively good" in Supernatural is the vampire Benjamin "Bennie" Lafitte. He aids the Winchesters during a time of great need. It doesn't turn out well for Bennie. Don't come back to read the rest until Season 8...

> Benjamin Lafitte was a vampire, turned by the ancient one known as The Old Man, who he worshipped as a god. However, fifty years ago, Benny fell in love with a Greek woman named Andrea Kormos, deciding to abandon his maker. The Old Man discovered this and killed Benny, condemning his soul to Purgatory, the realm where all monsters go when they die.

Comment: A case can be made for Meg at least partially redeeming herself throughout her interactions with the Winchesters, though.

Comment: @Roger Meg was the closest to a demon ally they ever had (At least she never screwed them with the frequency and ferocity Crowley did), but her motives were all selfish; she only allied with them in order to protect herself. At best you could consider her neutral

Comment: @JasonBaker Oh, I agree that she was never what you would call "good", but going from lawful evil even to just chaotic neutral is a partial redemption. And her compassion for Cas definitely didn't read as faked to me.

Comment: It just occurred to me that we do get some less ambiguously good "monsters" as guest characters: (Most of) the werewolf clan that Garth hooks up with in Season 9, the vampires in the season 2 episode "Bloodlust" (When we first meet Gordon), the werewolf girl Kate from the season 8 episode "Bitten". There are others you make arguments for being sympathetic, but those ones I would call pretty unambiguously "good guys", although they're not really allies of the Brothers. It's not really in-scope for the OP's question, but it ties into your last point about Benny

Comment: Crowley's behavior after the partial "cure" would seem to indicate at least the possibility of a demon turning good, although we never get to see it happen.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a good question, I have pondered this myself.

It's true that there have been supposedly good demons, such as Ruby, but a genuinely good demon is rare. I am currently on season 10 and thus far Crowley has helped the Winchester brothers numerous times, even taking Dean under his wing when dean was demonised! Sure, as a demon, but I do believe that Crowley could have a little good in him, and I know this could be blamed on his human blood bender, but deep down if he was truly evil he'd have never helped the brothers, they'd probably be dead if he was bad. Additionally, there's the fact that he trusted his mother even after she was awful to him as a child.

So my final answer is yes, a good demon can exist.

Answer (score 1):

(Season 5-8 spoilers may be ahead!)

Hello, I don't know if this counts fully as "good" but Meg teamed up with the boys a couple of times. And one time she didn't even tell the information Crowley needed when he captured her.

She had a little romance (if you call that) with Castiel.
In the wiki page of Supernatural it says that: " She fended Crowley off long enough for the boys to retrieve the Angel Tablet and escape before he killed her." ( supernatural.fandom.com/wiki/Meg_Masters_(Demon) )

So I think she took some pretty good actions.

Comment: You can link the source in you answer, that would make it more permanent as opposed to comments which are sometimes deleted